# trigonometry identity problems (undefined values problem)

Tags: trigonometry

> As you all know $$\tan(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$so, $$\cos(x)\cdot \tan(x)=\sin(x)$$ $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$ and $\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$ also $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=\text{undefined}$

However $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is not equal but is undefined because it is $\dfrac{1}{0}$ so does that mean $\dfrac{1}{0} \cdot 0=1$ in this case?

Comment: No.  The first statement is only true when the denominator is nonzero.  You **cannot** divide by $0$.  **Ever.**

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that a trig identity (or any identity) is true ONLY WHEN the constituent parts are defined. Consequently, the relation $\cos x \cdot \tan x = \sin x$ is NOT assumed to hold at $x = \pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac 10=\text{undefined}$

And you can *never* divide by $0$ and/or work with undefined numbers (why even call them numbers if they are undefined).

In this case, $0$ and $0$ do not "cancel each other out".

If you can argue that $\dfrac 10\cdot0=1$, then another person can pose an argument that $\dfrac10\cdot0=0$.

Therefore, it is senseless to define such an expression. $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}2\right)$ is *undefined* in mathematical terms.